# Docker compose platform option

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, docker-container

I am trying to build a container from a docker image that seems to be incompatible with M1 macs, it does work with my old laptop which is Intel architecture, after research I'm pretty sure ARM architecture is the issue. When I add the `platform linux/amd64` flag for my docker-compose it builds successfully, but I am not sure how `platform` works. For instance, what happens if I'm building on a Windows machine or some other OS?

Answer (score 0):

The `platform` option is not currently supported on docker-compose v3: https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5985

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate. See https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5985#issuecomment-683395676 and https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#platform